# I need to determine the interception location of three spheres when they are in different locations besides the origin.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I feel that this is pretty straight forward, but I can't seem to get the algebra correct when combining equations. I need to find the interception point $(x,y,z)$ of three spheres. I've been banging my head on this problem for several days now, so any help will be appreciated.

The equations of the spheres are...

1. $R^2=(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2$
2. $S^2=(x-g)^2+(y-h)^2+(z-j)^2$
3. $T^2=(x-n)^2+(y-o)^2+(z-p)^2$

All variables are known except the intercept location of (x,y,z). I'm writing an algorithm that will calculate this in excel, so ideally I'd prefer an equation for each x,y,z coordinate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: of course you know that three general spheres in $R^3$ might have none or just one  common point

Comment: @GCab- Yes, that's a good point, but in this application, there will always be a common point. This will be used for trilateration.

Comment: @AnotherUser, thanks. I'll look into it and try to reformat the equations.

Comment: sorry, actually if there is one point there is also a symmetric to that: so two or none points.

Comment: @GCab- yes, I simply meant that they should intersect. If there is a symmetric point, we can eliminate it using another process.

Answer (score 2):

The given equations of the three spheres are

$R^2 = (x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 + (z - c)^2\\
S^2 = (x - g)^2 + (y - h)^2 + (z - j)^2 \\
T^2 = (x - n)^2 + (y - o)^2 + (z - p)^2$

Subtracting the second equation from the first, results in

$ K_1 = -2 x (a - g) - 2 y (b - h) - 2 z(c - j) \hspace{20pt}(1)$

where

$K_1 = R^2 - S^2 + g^2 + h^2 + j^2 - a^2 - b^2 - c^2$

And subtracting the third equation from the first equation gives us

$ K_2 = -2 x(a - n) - 2 y (b - o) - 2 z (c - p)\hspace{20pt}(2) $

where

$ K_2 = R^2 - T^2 + n^2 + o^2 + p^2 - a^2 - b^2 - c^2$

Equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equations of planes and can be solved simultaneously using Gauss-Jordan elimination, and this will result in

$ (x, y, z) = (x_0, y_0, z_0) + t (v_1, v_2, v_3)\hspace{20pt} (3) $

where $x_0, y_0, z_0, v_1, v_2, v_3$ have known numeric values, and $t$ is a free parameter, i.e. $t \in \mathbb{R} $

Substituting (3) into one of the original equations of the spheres, we can solve for $t$ (there can be 2 values or 1 value or no solutions).  Once we have the values of $t$ we substitute that into $(3)$ to obtain the value of $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I sadly am a little confused about a few things. 

1) What are K1 and K2 in equations 1 and 2?
2) In equation 3, what are x0,y0,z0? Do you mean a,b,c? The center of the first sphere?
3) How do you calculate t in equation 3?

Comment: $K_1$ and $K_2$ are constants as defined by the two equations in terms of the other givens.  $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ is the outcome of Gauss-Jordan elimination of the linear system of the two equations $(1),(2)$.  This means that this linear system of two planes, has as its solution, a straight line passing through $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ and which is along the direction vector $(v_1, v_2, v_3)$.  To calculate $t$, substitute the expression for $(x,y,z)$ (which is a $3D$ line) into the equation of sphere 1 or sphere 2 or sphere 3 (any of the spheres works well). You'll have a quadratic equation in $t$.

Comment: Thank you Erin for walking me through this. Conceptually, I understand, but mathematically, I'm still confused. How do I calculate (v1,v2,v3). Can you walk me through how to calculate t? Additionally, can you confirm that (x0,y0,z0) is the center of one of the spheres listed above?

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You'll have to review your linear algebra.

Comment: I haven't taken a math class, let alone linear algebra in over 15 years. It is clear that my algebra skills are not up to this task to do it alone, which is exactly the reason why I've come here to ask this question. I appreciate your time and thank you for your response.